# RPM - Installing files

Tags: rpm, yum, rpmbuild

This is my first attempt at building an RPM, so pardon the noob-ish question. :)

I am able to build an rpm and deploy it with yum OK, but I cannot get the file to deploy to the right directory on the target server.  I just want to put a data file into the /tmp directory on the target server.

```
%install
mkdir -p tmp
cp %_builddir/myfile.dat %_builddir/tmp/myfile.dat

%files
%_builddir/tmp/myfile.dat
```

When I yum install the rpm on the target server, it puts myfile.dat into `%_builddir/tmp/myfile.dat` under the home directory.  I want to put it in /tmp

I tried removing the %_builddir in the %files section, but the rpm would not build.

```
%files
/tmp/myfile.dat
```

What am I missing?

Edit -------

This is the code that now works:

```
BuildRoot:  %{_tmppath}/%{name}-%{version}-%{release}-root-%(%{__id_u} -n)

%install
mkdir -p $RPM_BUILD_ROOT/tmp
cp $RPM_BUILD_DIR/myfile.dat $RPM_BUILD_ROOT/tmp/myfile.dat

%files
/tmp/myfile.dat
```

Comment: You are missing providing us with all the necessary information - you say the "rpm would not build" but for some reason you ignored the error.

Comment: BTW, most distros have a tool like "[tmpwatch](http://linux.about.com/library/cmd/blcmdl8_tmpwatch.htm)" that will erase files from `/tmp` if they haven't been used in a while. You should put it [somewhere else](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filesystem_Hierarchy_Standard#Directory_structure).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are three separate trees involved which you appear to be confusing with each other:

- the build directory as represented by `$RPM_BUILD_DIR` (it's probably best practice to use this rather than `%_builddir`)
- the build root as represented by `$RPM_BUILD_ROOT`
- the final target filesystem on the system(s) where the rpm gets installed

`%install` should copy files from the first to the second, but yours doesn't - that is your first mistake, coupled with the fact that your `mkdir` creates `tmp` in the wrong directory - it needs to be in the build root.

`%files` dictates which of the files in the second should be packaged into the rpm which then eventually get installed on the target system when the rpm is installed.  But crucially, the files listed in `%files` should be listed *relative to the build root*, so your second attempt at `%files` is the right one.  If you still get an error, I suggest you read it carefully.  I also strongly recommend you read a good guide to rpm building, for example: http://www.rpm.org/max-rpm/s1-rpm-inside-scripts.html